# Jquery Dialog Confirm Box Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, confirm

I have spent the last few days searching Stack & Web articles to see if I can find my own answers. It is time to consult the experts.

Code HTML

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are You Sure?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This cannot be changed later!</p>
</div>
```

Code Jquery

```
$(".myclass").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Choose This?': function() {

                var dataString = 'id='+ id ;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "runAjax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function() {
                        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('close');
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }
                });                                
            },

            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

return false;
});
```

Jquery dialog confirm box I am using works perfectly in every single way EXCEPT, dialog's paragraph segement shown below will not appear in the dialog box.

```
p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This cannot be changed later. Are you sure?</p>
```

I do have jquery.js, jquery-ui.js included in header. core.js runs in the footer of the pages which has the jquery function above along with a function for tipsy.js as well as a few other ajax events. Anyone see what I obviously cant?

EDIT: 
Trying to add this to jsFiddle caused me to look at my CSS a little closure and sure enough

```
#dialog-confirm { visbility: hidden;}
```

This was the cause of why I could not see the dialog content. However, I put that there weeks ago when I initially installed this feature because the paragraph content was being displayed on the page when it shouldn't be. Does anyone by chance have an idea why it might be showing in the page? it does disappear from the page when the dialog confirm box is opened.

EDIT 2:

```
#dialog-confirm { display: none; }
```

OYE....

Comment: can you send a jsfiddle of your code? with myclass element and styling ..

Answer (score 0):

It does appear in the dialog box, but your dialog height is set to be so small that you can't see it (you can see it if you scroll). This works (notice increased dialog height):

```
<a href="#" class="myclass">CLICK HERE</span>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are You Sure?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This cannot be changed later!</p>
</div>

$(".myclass").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Choose This?': function() {

                var dataString = 'id='+ id ;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "runAjax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function() {
                        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('close');
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }
                });                                
            },

            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppuuM/

Comment: I have thought about that and tried it again just to be sure. I still don't get that paragraph section showing no matter what height or width. I have .ui-dialog { font-size: 12px; ) set which still works fine in your js fiddle file with height 140